# How can I get an instance of a component to update its useState independently of others?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component that has several instances of another component as its children.

In the code for this child component, I have a useState. User can input a number in to a text box and it changes the state that's then reflected on the screen.

Problem is, it only ever works for the first child component. If I try and change the values in a different instance of the component, it carries over the values from the first edit made. How can I have each child component update itself with its relevant inputs?

Picture:
[image: Screenshot of two child components that both update off of one input]

Code for child component:

```
//This component is meant to be an individual dice roller
//Parts include a text box, a label and a roll button
//Props will be passed in to change the values of each component

import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { 
    Wrapper,
    Button,
    TextInput,

    } from "../../styles";

export const DiceComp = (props) => {
//==========Dicecomp Variables=========
let var_faces = props.DiceFaces;

//==========Dicecomp functions=========

    //Shorthand version of console.log
    //use the following for styled logs:
    //    "%c LOG TEXT", "font-weight:bold; font-color=blue; background: black; padding:5px"
    const bark = (input) => {
        console.log("%c"+ input, "font-weight:bold; font-color=blue; background: black; padding:5px");
    }

    //useEffect to trigger re-renders
    useEffect(() => {
        bark("useEffect fired")
        bark("var_count: "+ var_count+", var_bonus: "+var_bonus);
    }, [var_count, var_bonus])

    //Random number between two input numbers
    const randNumber = (min, max) => { 
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }

    //ONCHANGE FUNCTION: Change values of dice count or dice bonus
    const UpdateVars = () =>
    {
        bark("UpdateVars fired.");
        let countRef = parseInt(document.getElementById("id_Count").value);
        let bonusRef = parseInt(document.getElementById("id_Bonus").value);

        if(isNaN(countRef))
        {
            countRef = 1;
        }
        if(isNaN(bonusRef))
        {
            bonusRef = 1;
        }

        
        set_var_count(countRef);
        set_var_bonus(bonusRef);
        bark("States CHANGED:\nvar_count: "+var_count+"\nvar_bonus: "+var_bonus);
        
    }

    //ONCLICK FUNCTION: roll a dice, based on count, face and bonus of that dice
    const RollThisDice = (count, face, bonus) => {

    //Internal scope Variables
        set_var_count(parseInt(count));
        bark("On a d"+props.DiceFaces+" roll, var_count was set to: " +var_count);
        var_faces = parseInt(face);
        set_var_bonus(parseInt(bonus));
        bark("States CHANGED:\nvar_count: "+var_count+"\nvar_bonus: "+var_bonus);

        if(isNaN(var_count))
        {
            set_var_count(1);
            bark("State CHANGED:\nvar_count: "+var_count);
        }

        if(isNaN(var_bonus))
        {
            set_var_bonus(1);
            bark("State CHANGED:\nvar_bonus: "+var_bonus);
        }
   
        let results = [];

        try{
    
            //Roll the dice, generate the result as many times as needed
        for(let i = 0; i < var_count; i++)
            {
                let result = ((randNumber(var_count, var_faces) + var_bonus))
                results.push(result);
                
            }
            bark("Rolls made: "+results+". (Each roll has "+var_bonus+" to it)");
        }

        catch(error)
        {
            bark("ERROR:\nPants browned in RollThisDice function.")
            bark(error)
        }
}   

// usestate to track and change count of dice and bonus
const [var_count, set_var_count] = useState(1);
const [var_bonus, set_var_bonus] = useState(0);
bark("States initialised:\nvar_count: "+var_count+"\nvar_bonus: "+var_bonus);

return(
<Wrapper inputFlexDirection="row">
    <TextInput id="id_Count" defaultValue={var_count} onChange={() => UpdateVars()}/> {/* Number of dice to roll */}
    d{var_faces}+
    <TextInput id="id_Bonus" defaultValue={var_bonus} onChange={() => UpdateVars()}/>    {/* Bonus to this dice roll */}
    <Button onClick={() => RollThisDice(var_count, var_faces, var_bonus)}>{var_count}d{var_faces}+{var_bonus}</Button>
</Wrapper>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add keys to the different instances of the child component you are using Plus make the input ids different too for each instance of the child component .Try this and see if it works